# Sealed class in Kotlin, Incompatible types error cannot return parent type

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this sealed class represent the view state

```
sealed class ViewState<out ResultType>(
) {
    data class Success<ResultType>(val data: ResultType?) : ViewState<ResultType>()
    data class Error(val message: String) : ViewState<Nothing>()
    object Loading : ViewState<Nothing>()

}
```

here I use viewState

```
fun <T, A> performGetOperation(databaseQuery: () -> LiveData<T>)): LiveData<ViewState<T>> =
        liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
        emit(ViewState.Loading)
        val cache: LiveData<ViewState.Success<T>> = databaseQuery.invoke()
                    .map { ViewState.Success<T>(it) }

        emitSource(cache)
        }
```

this line is crazy emitSource(cache) give me emitSource(cache)

```
Required:
LiveData<ViewState<T>>
Found:
LiveData<ViewState.Success<T>>
```

Comment: try returning `LiveData<ViewState.Success<T>>` from function instead of `LiveData<ViewState<T>>`

Comment: emit(ViewState.Loading) will shout

Comment: Could you pleae format your code better. You have lots of unnecessary empty lines. Which line in your code gives you that error?

Comment: @ChristianB  this line         emitSource(cache)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a simple type definition problem.
You defined `cache` as `LiveData<ViewState.Success<T>>` which does not match the returning type of `LiveData<ViewState<T>>`.

You have to change the type from `val cache: LiveData<ViewState.Success<T>>` to `val cache: LiveData<ViewState<T>>`.

Here is the correct functions:

```kotlin
fun <T, A> performGetOperation(databaseQuery: () -> LiveData<T>)): LiveData<ViewState<T>> = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
  emit(ViewState.Loading)
  
  val cache: LiveData<ViewState<T>> = databaseQuery.invoke()
                    .map { ViewState.Success<T>(it) }

  emitSource(cache)
}
```

Comment: LiveData<ViewState.Success<T>> is sub type of LiveData<ViewState<T>>.

Comment: I know. I can not explain why the compiler can not infer this. But changing that will make it work. Can you confirm this?

Comment: "LiveData<ViewState.Success<T>> is sub type of LiveData<ViewState<T>>" It isn't; please see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance